# MAMP Pro running multiple hosts through to xip.io only resolving to one host

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro, xip.io

I'm using MAMP Pro v3.5 for local development. I have multiple dev sites running successfully without a problem. When it came to testing a site on my phone, I used the out of the both 'Name resolution [x] via Xip.io (LAN only)' option under the hosts tab. The first host I turned that on with was fine and worked very well (using address like www.siteone.dev.192.168.0.10.xip.io).

The problem came though when I attempted to setup a second dev site on Xip.io using the above method. Now using a different URL (using address like www.sitetwo.dev.192.168.0.10.xip.io) for the second dev site, no matter what I try, I get the first host that was setup rather than the expected second.

Is this a bug with MAMP Pro, or it's just not capable. I've tried turning off the 1st host I setup with MAMP Pro, but it still shows up as the site that is getting served under the second xip.io address I setup.

Would really appreciate one of the MAMP people to respond and confirm if this is expected behaviour. An extended Google search didn't turn up anything.

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: Exact same issue here, did you manage to resolve?